# absolute offset height and scrollTo

Tags: jquery

this code position a div tag according to .offset() and scrolls down to the div element.. the div tag is positioned right but the scrollTo scrolls way over?

I cant really figure out whats wrong?

```
var offset = row.offset();
$('html').animate({
        scrollTop : offset.top
    },
    500,
    'linear',
    function(){
        var highlight = $('<div class="insert_highlight" style="top:'+offset.top+'px; left:'+offset.left+'px; width:'+row.width()+'px; height:'+row.height()+'px"></div>').appendTo($(document.body))
            .delay(800)
            .fadeOut(1200, 'linear', function(){
                highlight.remove();
            });
    });
```

style

```
div.insert_highlight {
    position:absolute;
    background:#00ff00;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

EDIT:

I dont know if it could have something to do with this? all content on the page is placed in this table

```
<table style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-top:130px">
...
```

even if I replace the padding-top with this the scrollTo scrolls way over

```
<div style="height:130px"></div>
```

EDIT again:

I have now pasted a print screen in photoshop to measure the position of the appended div and the top position is right...

Comment: I imagine it's something to do with the absolute positioning. What happens if you take out all the bit about adding another element for a few seconds and removing it?

Comment: if I escape the part with "var highlight = $('<div ..." its still the same

Comment: I have now pasted a print screen in photoshop to measure the position of the appended div and the top position is right...